# How to Add a blue background to product which cost more than 3,00€

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a blue background to the product which costs more than 3,00€ using vanilla javascript. Thanks

```
<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Brocoli</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">3,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Avocado</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">3,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Tomato</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">2,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [No effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9078341)

Comment: Add another class to the divs where the price > 3,00€?

Comment: use `innerHTML` in JS to check if the price is > 3,00€ (need an integer though) and then use JS to add/remove a class to change the style.

Comment: Well you could have included in the post the part where you create conditions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one solution is to use jquery for example:

```js
$(".grocery-item__normal-price").each( function(){
  //keep only number and change , to .
  var number = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[^\d,.]/g,"").replace(",","."));
  if(number >= 3) $(this).addClass("morethan3");
});
```

```css
.morethan3{
  background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Brocoli</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">3,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Avocado</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">3,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Tomato</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">2,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're looking for.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.grocery-item');

items.forEach(item => {
  const priceElement = item.querySelector('.grocery-item__normal-price');
  const [itemPrice] = priceElement.textContent.split(' ');
  
  if (parseFloat(itemPrice.replace(',','.')) >= 3.00) {
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
})
```

```html
 <div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Brocoli</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">3,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Avocado</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">3,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grocery-item">
   <div class="description-offre">
    <a href="#">Tomato</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grocery-item__price">
    <div class="grocery-item__normal-price">2,99 €</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much fortunee for your help and Thanks to everyone who participated with my questions

Comment: You're welcome! Can you accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: Yes accept it, it helped me but can you demonstrate more this line of code i didn't get it : const [itemPrice] = priceElement.textContent.split(' ');. Thank you

Comment: To accept this answer you have to click the checkmark below the vote icon. I'm using array destructuring on that line because `.split()` returns an array you can also do `const itemPrice = priceElement.textContent.split(' ')[0];` to get the same result

Comment: You can read about [Array destructuring here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/array-and-object-destructuring-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks, awesome fortunee I really appreciate your help

Comment: Glad to help! @OuailTayarth are you considering using jquery now as opposed to vanilla js?